# NoReverseMatch at /login/ (Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am starting with Django 3 and python 3.8, and I have had a problem, I am trying to start the session and when I press the **Ingresar** button I get this error:

[image]

I have tried many things to try to solve it but I cannot, although I have found similar problems, the solutions they give have not worked for me.

This is the code I have so far:

**principal urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    
    path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/', views.index)
]
```

**app urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/index', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

**base_generic.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  {% block title %}<title>Read Praxis</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">All books</a></li>
          <li><a href="">All authors</a></li>
      </ul>
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.0.1">
    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/sign-in/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'assets/dist/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }
    </style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/login.css' %}">
</head>

<body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <img class="mb-4" src="{% static 'images/rpp_logo.png' %}" alt="" width="150">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Por favor ingresa</h1>
        <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Aqu&iacute; tu usuario" required autofocus name="username">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Aqu&iacute; tu contraseña" required name="password">
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Recu&eacute;rdame
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Read Praxis Project</p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Bienvenido {{ user.usermane | upper }}</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
```

The truth is that I don't know what else I could do, if someone has a solution I would really appreciate it

Comment: Did you add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, I did, so not is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is giving error because you have given same path for `'index/'` at 2 places.

Remove it from **app urls.py** and replace it at **principal urls.py** like below.

> **principal urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

> **app urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

Comment: @KattyZambrano, do let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @KattyZambrano, Use my code above urls in the same order and check. Error should not come actually.